# Populating a dataframe with output from anomaly detection

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to feed the output data from an outlier detector into a pandas dataframe. There are multiple columns representing each time series that I want to run the outlier detector on. They are "1", "2"...."n". Here is a small snippet of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Datetime": [2016-6-13,2016-6-14,2016-6-15,2016-6-16],
                  "CompanyID": [271, 271, 271, 271],
                  "1": [140, 143, 142, 143],
                  "2": [42, 43, 49, 230]})
```

I do not think the full code is of use, but here it is anyways:

```
#support vector machines outlier detection
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm

def find_outliers(ts, perc=0.01, figsize=(15,5)):
    ## fit svm
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    ts_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(ts.values.reshape(-1,1))
    model = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=perc, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.01)
    model.fit(ts_scaled)
    ## dtf output
    df_outliers = ts.to_frame(name="ts")
    df_outliers["index"] = ts.index
    df_outliers["outlier"] = model.predict(ts_scaled)
    df_outliers["outlier"] = df_outliers["outlier"].apply(lambda
                                              x: 1 if x==-1 else 0)

    ## plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax.set(title="Outliers detection: found"
           +str(sum(df_outliers["outlier"]==1)))
    ax.plot(df_outliers["index"], df_outliers["ts"],
            color="black")
    ax.scatter(x=df_outliers[df_outliers["outlier"]==1]["index"],
               y=df_outliers[df_outliers["outlier"]==1]['ts'],
               color='red')
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

```
for column in df.columns[2:]:
    find_outliers(df[column])
```

The output from the anomaly detector from running

```
print(df_outliers["outlier"] == 1)
print(type(df_outliers))
```

inside the function is:

```
Datetime
2016-06-13     True
2016-06-14     True
2016-06-15     True
2016-06-16     True
2016-06-17     True
 
2021-02-03    False
2021-02-04    False
2021-02-05    False
2021-02-06    False
2021-02-07     True
Name: outlier, Length: 1425, dtype: bool
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I want this transformed so that I get a dataframe that looks like the input data, only that it contains True/False for each column, so "1", "2", ... "n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return the outliers column from your function and overwrite the column with the bool values of the return.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Datetime": [2016-6-13,2016-6-14,2016-6-15,2016-6-16],
                  "CompanyID": [271, 271, 271, 271],
                  "1": [140, 143, 142, 143],
                  "2": [42, 43, 49, 230]})

#support vector machines outlier detection
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def find_outliers(ts, perc=0.01, figsize=(15,5)):
    ## fit svm
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    ts_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(ts.values.reshape(-1,1))
    model = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=perc, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.01)
    model.fit(ts_scaled)
    ## dtf output
    df_outliers = ts.to_frame(name="ts")
    df_outliers["index"] = ts.index
    df_outliers["outlier"] = model.predict(ts_scaled)
    df_outliers["outlier"] = df_outliers["outlier"].apply(lambda
                                              x: 1 if x==-1 else 0)

    ## plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax.set(title="Outliers detection: found"
           +str(sum(df_outliers["outlier"]==1)))
    ax.plot(df_outliers["index"], df_outliers["ts"],
            color="black")
    ax.scatter(x=df_outliers[df_outliers["outlier"]==1]["index"],
               y=df_outliers[df_outliers["outlier"]==1]['ts'],
               color='red')
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.show()

    # Return outlier column here
    return(df_outliers['outlier'])


for column in df.columns[2:]:
    # Capture outlier column
    outliers = find_outliers(df[column])
    # Overwrite values with bool outlier values
    df[column] = outliers.astype(bool)
```

Output

```
   Datetime  CompanyID      1      2
0      1997        271  False   True
1      1996        271  False  False
2      1995        271  False  False
3      1994        271  False   True
```